# "Is it left-handed?" Or "Is it for left-handed?"

Tags: adjectives, prepositional-phrases

> *"Is it left-handed?"* ***OR*** *"Is it **for** left-handed?"*

Which one is correct way to ask whether something is specially made for left-handed?

My homework:

> A left-handed guitar

is a valid sentence and this assures me that my way of asking is proper.

> *I bought a guitar for you.* ~ *Thanks, but **is it left-handed?***

Somehow, to me, this way of asking seems better. Because *left-handed* is an adjective which in this context better take preposition *for*:

> *I bought a guitar for you.* ~ *Thanks, but **is it for left-handed** (like me, which is understood)?*

Comment: If you want a noun, and think *a left-handed person* is a bit too long, there is another word, *left-hander*.

Answer (score 6):

The proper way to say it would be "Is it left-handed?"

If you say "is it FOR left-handed" then the question is, left-handed what? The thing that 'left-handed' is describing in the first example is "it" (the object you are asking about). In the second example, however, "Is it for left-handed", the thing being described as left-handed is missing, making the sentence sound incomplete and awkward. The object being described could be completed as "Is it for left handed writing/playing/people/children/drumming/etc." To make it correct you would have to include what is left-handed.

Comment: It may be interesting to note that this is a case of a _transferred epithet_: strictly speaking, it is not the guitar that is left-handed, but the person that will use it. It is very common and readily understood, but it may be confusing when you think of it too much. :)

Comment: How would you form a question out of *It is a left-handed guitar*? With an answer yes/no.

Comment: I would say, "Is it a left-handed guitar?" or the slightly modified "Is the guitar for left-handed people?"

Comment: This answer nails it. "I bought you some new golf clubs." "Thanks, but are they left-handed?" Sure, you can add the word _clubs_ after _left-handed_, but it's quite unnecessary in informal conversation. Another informal way you could refer to the person instead of the clubs would be, "Thanks, but are they for lefties?"

Comment: @J.R. *lefty* is the exact word used in India. But was afraid of InE again! :)

Comment: You could also ask "is it for the left-handed?" Note the *the* in there. That (at least to me) puts more than normal emphasis on the question, though. That also allows some more variation (usable by the left-handed, useful for the left-handed, etc.) *Is it left-handed?* is definitely the normal way to ask this.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly reasonable to describe an object designed to be used by left-handed people as itself being "left-handed". But, as discussed in [Peramia's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/31977/4468), "Is it for left-handed?" is an incomplete sentence because "left-handed" is an adjective. You could either say "Is it for left-handed people?" or "Is it for left-handers?"

"Is it for lefties" is rather informal and I probably wouldn't use it myself. I don't think it's at all offensive but it seems to be more common for left-handed people to use it to talk about themselves, and I'm a "righty". I would also avoid "Is it for the left-handed?" as, while grammatically correct, it feels rather laboured. Also, for example, disabled people tend to dislike being referred to as "the disabled" and "the left-handed" is the same kind of thing, though, again, rather less likely to cause any real offense.

Comment: In the context of 'a beautiful flower', I may tell someone - *I've bought a flower for you.* ~ *Is it beautiful?*; *Yes, it is. Just like you!*. Beautiful is an adjective but still used that way.

Comment: @MaulikV I don't understand your point. The question "Is it beautiful?" makes perfect sense: the adjective "beautiful" is applied to the pronoun "it". Likewise, in "Is it left-handed?", the adjective "left-handed" is being applied to the pronoun "it". But in "Is it for left-handed?", the adjective "left-handed" is not being applied to the pronoun "it".

Comment: mea culpa. I read it without *for*. However, I remember that some words don't take any article (especially physically challenged people--say--deaf). *"Is it for deaf"* is okay. However, it serves as a noun but somehow I am getting confused with *left-handed.*

Comment: @MaulikV No, "Is it for deaf?" is *not* OK, for exactly the same reason that "Is it for left-handed?" is not OK. "Deaf" is an adjective. It can serve as a noun with the article ("the deaf") but, like disabled people, deaf people prefer to be called "deaf people" than "the deaf"

Comment: I had read a headline somewhere... "something for deaf". Not getting the link though I tried just now.

Comment: Can *left-handed* be a noun, in any case? What do you think?

Comment: @MaulikV Newspaper headlines often omit articles for brevity. Don't use them as a model for what is and is not grammatical English. Yes, "left-handed" can be a noun but it would only be used as "the left-handed", to refer to left-handed people in general.

Comment: I know what's headlinese. It was something else. Anyway thanks for your input